# Knitting GA data in RStudio: Error in identical(body, FALSE) : object 'redirect.uri' not found

Tags: r, google-analytics, r-markdown, knitr

I am using the `rga` package to track my Google Analytics data.

When I create a script in R, I successfully retrieve data from GA:

```
library(rga)
library(curl)

rga.open(instance="ga")

x <- ga$getProfiles()
id <- x[3,1] # here we select the ID of the webpage we are tracking

visits <- ga$getData(id, 
                      start.date= as.Date("2016-01-01"), 
                      end.date = "today", 
                      metrics = "ga:visits, ga:pageviews, ga:organicSearches",
                      dimensions = "ga:date", 
                      sort = "", filters = "", segment = "",
                      start = 1, max = 1000,
                      batch = TRUE)
```

However, when I copy/paste this code in a RMarkdown file, inside a chunk, I get this error when converting it to HTML/PDF/Word:

> Error in identical(body, FALSE) : object 'redirect.uri' not found Calls:  ...  -> request_build -> body_config -> identical Execution halted

How can I create reports about my GA data using R Markdown? How can I solve this problem